# Full text search using postgresql-8.4 and django

Tags: django, postgresql, full-text-search

Full text search with mysql & django can be done using following django api query

```
Entry.objects.filter(headline__search="search text")
```

This returns result set properly.But this can't be used with postgresql, while using getting an exception which is shown below

```
Full-text search is not implemented for this database backend
```

How can i imlement full text search with postgresql & django which is same as that of  django-mysql full text search?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try

```
Entry.objects.filter(headline__contains="search text")
```

or `__icontains` for case-insensitive search.

As the [django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#search) says `__search` only works with MySQL for now.

Comment: @ Rohan,This query returns the result set which having exact match, Is there any option for including partial match also?

Comment: @Jafarali, I don't think `__contains` does exact match (ref : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#contains), for exact match you need to use `__exact`. However, it would check for both (all) words given to look for.

Comment: @ Rohan,Suppose  checking for a match against the record "welcome to the new world" with query  __contains="welcome world" , returns zero records.

Answer (score 2):

You may try [Haystack](http://haystacksearch.org/) or user-created library [djorm-ext-pgfulltext](https://github.com/niwibe/djorm-ext-pgfulltext). Also it is useful to read https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/4676 and http://bogdan-ivanov.com/entry/full-text-search-postgresql-and-django/

Answer (score 0):

For user reading this question these days:

PostgreSQL Full-Text-Search support is present since Django 1.10 (2016) by the module [django.contrib.postgres.search](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/postgres/search/) .